# Content-Length in response header replaced by Transfer-Encoding: chunked by apache

Tags: apache2

While sending large file stream in response to the browser the Content-Length header i manually set gets replaced by Transfer-Encoding: chunked in apache httpd 2.2.23 (64bit) for all files >2GB. This makes the browser unsure of the total size of the file and hence the total file size in the browser download progress appears as '?'. For files < 2GB the Content-Length appears just fine. Wondering what could be causing apache to override the  Content-Length header with Transfer-Encoding: chunked for large files. How can I prevent this?

I did try to turn on mod_deflate and also tried to set following environment properties as read in some other threads. But no luck.

```
    SetEnv force-response-1.0
    SetEnv downgrade-1.0
    SetEnv nokeepalive
```